# In Go, how to write functions that take tuple arguments?

Tags: go, tuples, ternary-operator

I'm new to Go and I am translating a Python program to Go.

I'm a big fan of ternary operator so I quickly implemented

```
func t2(test bool, true_val, false_val string) string {
    if test {
        return true_val
    } else {
        return false_val
    }
}
```

which works fine.

Unfortunately I had this in Python: `a = 'hi', 'hello' if xxx else 'bye', 'goodbye'`

How does my ternary operator would have to be written for tuples of strings?

I have tried:

- generics but learnt they don't exist in Go
- do `func t2(test bool, true_val, false_val (string, string)) (string, string)` but it doesn't compile
- typedef: `type s2 string, string` and `func t2(test bool, true_val, false_val s2) s2` but it doesn't compile

Thanks

Comment: As you saw there's no generics in Go. You should embrace Go instead of trying to code as if it was Python. Your "ternary" would be considered bad practice in Go.

Comment: @Zoidberg Noted, thanks. I thought that multiple values returned by functions were tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Implementing with 2 `string` return values

It could look something like this:

```
func t(test bool, true1, true2, false1, false2 string) (string, string) {
    if test {
        return true1, true2
    }
    return false1, false2
}
```

Testing it:

```
a1, a2 := t(false, "hi", "hello", "bye", "goodbye")
fmt.Println(a1, a2)

a1, a2 = t(true, "hi", "hello", "bye", "goodbye")
fmt.Println(a1, a2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DlbektI_g2)):

```
bye goodbye
hi hello
```

#### Implementing with slice `[]string` return value

It might be easier to read and work with if we implement it with `string` slices: `[]string`.

```
func t(test bool, trueVal []string, falseVal []string) []string {
    if test {
        return trueVal
    }
    return falseVal
}
```

Testing it:

```
trueVal := []string{"hi", "hello"}
falseVal := []string{"bye", "goodbye"}

a := t(false, trueVal, falseVal)
fmt.Println(a)

a = t(true, trueVal, falseVal)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/iwfI1xFIkl)):

```
[bye goodbye]
[hi hello]
```

#### Implementing with a wrapper `struct` return value

You may also choose to create a wrapper `struct` to hold an arbitrary number of values (even having arbitrary / different types):

```
type Pair struct {
    v1, v2 string
}

func t(test bool, trueVal Pair, falseVal Pair) Pair {
    if test {
        return trueVal
    }
    return falseVal
}
```

Testing it:

```
trueVal := Pair{"hi", "hello"}
falseVal := Pair{"bye", "goodbye"}

a := t(false, trueVal, falseVal)
fmt.Println(a)

a = t(true, trueVal, falseVal)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3pDfRwjk-C)):

```
{bye goodbye}
{hi hello}
```

Comment: By the way, how to do if the tuple is `string, int` ?

Comment: @Thomas Then the function could look like this: `func t(test bool, true1 string, true2 int, false1 string, false2 int) (string, int)` and everything can be the same. With slices, the slice type may be `[]interface{}` which can hold any value, but using it requires type assertion.

Comment: @Thomas Please see edited answer. I also added a 3rd solution (with a wrapper `struct`), which may hold arbitrary number of values and with different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array (or even a slice if it the number is variable):

```
func iff(test bool, true_val, false_val [2]string) (string, string) {
    if test {
        return true_val[0], true_val[1]
    }
    return false_val[0], false_val[1]
}
```

test:

```
func main() {
    a, b := iff(false, [2]string{"hi", "hello"}, [2]string{"bye", "goodbye"})
    fmt.Println(a, b)

    a, b = iff(true, [2]string{"hi", "hello"}, [2]string{"bye", "goodbye"})
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```